# Ajax url parameter issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

When i do a **Ajax** request , for the url mentioned below , it is concatenating the url value which i have mentioned along with the **pathname** of the URL of the page.

**JSP:**

```
<form:form modelAttribute="createtask" id="create-task-form" name="create-task-form">
    <div class="task">
        <form:input path="taskName" placeholder="enter task"/>
        <c:url value="/createtask/${todo.todoId }" var="createtaskUrl" />
        <a id="create-task" href="${createtaskUrl }"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

**Jquery Ajax call:**

```
$("a#create-task").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var todoid = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1,this.href.length);
    var createTaskForm = $("#create-task-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type        :   "POST",
        url         :   "createtask/"+todoid,
        data        :   createTaskForm,
        dataType    :   "text",
        success     :   function(data){
            console.log("Created Task successfully..");
            $("section#taskviewer").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I know it concatenates with the context path of the application. For example if my application context path is 
localhost:8080/SpringMVCPractice/ and the page in which I do the Ajax request is

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCPractice/viewTodo/110
```

and when I do a ajax request by clicking the anchor tag, the url it takes is

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCPractice/viewTodo/createtask/110
```

Why it is not taking `localhost:8080/SpringMVCPractice/createtask/110` ?

Any suggestion? I am relatively new to Ajax.

Comment: I think its getting appended from contextPath, as you mentioned url = createtask/"+todoid so it would only append this much in your contextPath

Comment: @ManojP . Why is getting appended ?? Any idea

Comment: @NishitMaheta do i need to append it to form ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

by specifying the url as,

```
url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createtask/"+todoid,
```

Comment: Thanks Brijesh , it works :). But i have included the ajax piece in my viewtodo.jsp page . But the same is not working when i place this code in a exterior javascript file.?

Comment: @402951 it is because here we have used jstl.. which works on jsp page only

Comment: i know it is not possible to use jstl in .js file. Is there a way to achieve the same thing by placing the Ajax code in exterior javascript file , cause i am having all JS related stuff in a separate .js page. Any suggestion ?

Comment: One way is to collect `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in a js variable in your jsp page ,you have to write this one line, and then use that variable in your ajax url to append.